# How to use SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose to display custom loading message?

Tags: 2010, development, modal-dialog

I use a modal dialog to display my custom aspx page. However, the page takes some time to load, and I would like to provide custom loading message while the modal dialog is loading. I found out [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/78627/show-a-message-while-loading-modal-dialog?rq=1) I can do this with `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose`, but how exactly do I use it? Where and how am I supposed to put it to display custom loading message prior to showing the modal dialog?

This is how I open a modal dialog (on button click):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">    
    function OpenDialog(targetUrl) {
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();        
        options.url = targetUrl;        
        options.autoSize = true;
        options.allowMaximize = false;
        options.allowClose = true;

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);        
    }
</script>
```

Where in this code does `SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose` fit and how? I'd like it to automatically close after the page in modal dialog has been loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the 'Waiting' dialog, for example, you can call it on page load (document.ready), then when the window is finished loading, close the dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  window.parent.eval("window.waitDialog = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose('Loading MySites', '', 90, 450);");

});

$( window ).load(function() {  
     if (window.parent.waitDialog != null) 
     {
        window.parent.waitDialog.close();
     }
});
```

Check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408140%28v=office.14%29.aspx) link for the parms (Title, msg, height, width). The main lines you are looking for is window.parent.eval... & window.parent.waitDialog.close(), you just need to hook it into a trigger that makes sense for you.

Comment: @w128 really? eval as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do:

```
function OpenDialog(targetUrl) {
        var waitScreen = SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose("Loading", "Please wait");
        var options = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();        
        options.url = targetUrl;        
        options.autoSize = true;
        options.allowMaximize = false;
        options.allowClose = true;
        options.args = waitScreen; //pass the reference of the wait screen to the dialog

        SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);        
    }
```

Then, from within the opened dialog:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var waitScreen = SP.UI.ModalDialog.get_childDialog().get_args();
   waitScreen.close();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use an approach like the following

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var notificationID = SP.UI.Notify.addNotification("<font color='#AA0000'>In Progress..</font> <img src='/_Layouts/Images/kpiprogressbar.gif' align='absmiddle'> ", true);

        //do your stuff

        SP.UI.Notify.removeNotification(notificationID);
        window.location.reload();

    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, however this is not related to a modal dialog, it merely display a notification.

Comment: why don't you put your "OpenDialog" method in the "do your stuff" section and remove the method as soon as the dialog is loaded? Or am I understanding your requirements wrong?