# When site opened, get pop-up

Tags: sharepoint-designer, site-collection, popup

I have a site collection in Sharepoint Designer 2013. When my homepage opened, I want to get a pop-up. The pop-up is a image. It isn't a webpage.  How can do this? Is there such a thing?

Answer (score 1):

To achieve that in a supportable way you need to add a javascript `CustomAction` to your `Web`'s [UserCustomActions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.usercustomactions(v=office.15).aspx) property. Pop-up can be implemented by using either the standard javascript `window.open()` or SharePoint's `SP.UI.ModalDialog`.

See, for example:

http://github.com/OfficeDev/PnP

[How to use SP.UI.ModalDialog.showWaitScreenWithNoClose to display custom loading message?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/100910/how-to-use-sp-ui-modaldialog-showwaitscreenwithnoclose-to-display-custom-loading)

and other questions tagged [modal-dialog](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modal-dialog)

Comment: I don't want to redirect to an url. I'd like when homepage is opened , my image open.The image should have a close button. When users click close button, image is closed.

Comment: I said nothing about redirects, did I? Should the image have a hyperlink to take the user elsewhere like when you open a public site and it offers you to download an app?

Comment: No, the image doesn't open a public site. It's a notification image for users, only. And it doesn't download an app @Alexey

Comment: Does this response or another one answer your question? Please mark appropriately or post your own answer if you have one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Otherwise, you can add a HTML form web part on your home page and edit the source to look like

```
<script>window.open(...)</script>
```

See [window.open documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) for details.

Comment: I want to open an image in pop-up. How can I do this?

Comment: I'll  edit my other answer to respond to this question a bit later