# Processing dialog for SharePoint 2013 remote event receiver - Item Added

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Is it possible to have a dialog, "Waiting for the Item to be added" for SharePoint 2013 custom list to which a remote event receiver is attached (Provider hosted app with App installed event), having an ItemAdded event. If an item is added, now the list add item page is seen as stuck, instead a user friendly dialog "Please wait for the item to be added" need to be displayed.

Any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly confident this is possible.

The page seems stuck because it wait's until the the event finishes, assuming it's a Synchronous event. I'm not sure on what you are doing but if the page redirects or reloads when done adding the item you can simply display some sort of message right before the code to add the item executes.

SPLongOperation might be a good way to handle this is you can modify or use C#. Alternatively you can use JavaScript to show an overlay, there's some good information here: [How do I show a loading div when opening a modal dialog from a CustomAction?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/24391/how-do-i-show-a-loading-div-when-opening-a-modal-dialog-from-a-customaction).